# Problem solving ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Doing my homework on analytical mechanics I stucked on the equation of the next form: $$\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2=f(y)$$ I need to find dependence of $y$ on $t$. I had an idea to differentiate it to make it linear relative to $\frac{dy}{dt}$ term. But on the RHS there is a nasty function which will become much bigger, moreover I will need additional initial condition. Maybe you could show me some other more convenient method? I know this should be something simple but I slept bad tonight and I just need your directions.

Comment: What's wrong with $\frac{dy}{dt}= \sqrt{f(y)}$. $\frac{dy}{\sqrt{f(y)}}= dt$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}= -\sqrt{f(y)}$, $\frac{dy}{\sqrt{f(y)}}= -dt$?

Comment: @user247327 the RHS is complex and i will not be able to integrate $\frac{dy}{+-\sqrt{f(y)}}$

Comment: I am searching for a method with substirution or something to make second order go away

Comment: Second order? Do you mean $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$ instead of $\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2$ by any chance? Because $\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}$ is the second derivative of $y$ and $\left(\frac{dy}{dt}\right)^2$ is the square of the first derivative of $y$.

Comment: @Wauzl I mean not the order of the derivative but the square of the first derivative.

Answer (score 1):

You can just take the square root and you will have two answers after separating the variables and integrating.

$$\frac{dy}{dt}=\pm\sqrt{f(y)}\iff \frac{dy}{\pm\sqrt{f(y)}}=dt\iff\int \frac{dy}{\pm\sqrt{f(y)}}=\int dt$$

Solution 1: $$\boxed{\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{f(y)}}=t+c}$$

Solution 2: $$\boxed{\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{f(y)}}=-t+c}$$

I don't think you can do any better without knowing more about $f(y)$.